# Animate UICollectionViewCell collapsing

Tags: ios, animation, uicollectionview, resize

I'm trying to animate the height of a UICollectionViewCell when the user taps on it.

The basic functionality is working as expected. It collapses and expands when tapped BUT my UICollectionViewCells are customized and have a headerView and a contentView so when I animate the height it collapses the contentView to 0 and only the header is visible vise versa on expanding. The problem is that the contentView is just there/gone and is not animating as the cell (its superview) itself.

See the screenshots for a better understanding:

The animation when I tap on a header (red). The contentView is instantaneously visible but the cell animates behind it:

[image]

After the animation has finished everything is fine:
[image]

Tapping again collapses the cell as expected but the contentView (blue) is hidden instantaneously:
[image]

The implementation is done by performing batch updates on the collectionViewLayout. I think its just a little flag or something but I'm searching for a while now.

After disabling auto layout in my custom UICollectionViewCell it's working perfectly BUT this seems more like a workaround to me. So I'll leave this question open.